# check if an object has length?

Tags: javascript

I have to loop through to check an object to set missing arguments.

Initially, I had a check where when `Object.keys().length` was empty then a missing array was created for that object variable.

the check was

```
   if (!Object.keys(obj).length) {
          missing.push(obj);
    }
```

and was working well as obj always had keys, later there were cases where obj was set as `{}` which obviously doesn't have keys, how can this be checked?

Comment: This is very unclear, at least to me.

Comment: could you use jquery?

Comment: I'm confused, in which cases does your code not work and how *should* it work?

Comment: @user3803784 did my answer solve your problem?

Answer (score 2):

`Object.keys(obj).length` doesn't work in all browsers because of JScript DontEnum [Bug](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/ECMAScript_DontEnum_attribute#JScript_DontEnum_Bug)

try with this pure javascript function (**updated**)

```
function isEmpty(obj) {     
        if (obj == null) 
            return true;
        if (obj === undefined)
            return true;

        if (obj.length === 0)  
            return true;

        if (obj.length > 0)    
            return false;

        for (var key in obj) {
            if(obj.hasOwnProperty(prop))
            return false;
        }

        return true;
    }
```

another solution could be

`Object.getOwnPropertyNames(obj).length == 0`

> getOwnPropertyNames returns an array of all properties (enumerable or
>   not) found directly upon a given object.

refer [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/getOwnPropertyNames) for getOwnPropertyNames documentation

if you can use jquery there is this function that should help you

```
jQuery.isEmptyObject(obj);
```

refer [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.isEmptyObject/) for documentation